# Buildx failed with: ERROR: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:xxx": invalid content digest in response: invalid checksum digest format

Tags: github-actions, pipeline, docker-registry

I have a react app and I'm trying to set up ci/cd for this application.

I'm getting an error like this in GitHub actions and I get this error during "exporting to image"

```
name: "deploy-prod"
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "configure-ci/cd-pipeline-to-frontend-repo"

env:
  REPOSITORY_NAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
  REACT_APP_BASENAME: "FooApp"

jobs:
  build-backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: string
        uses: ASzc/change-string-case-action@v1
        with:
          string: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_HOST }}/${{ github.repository }}:build-${{ github.run_number }}

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.string.outputs.lowercase }}
          build-args: |
            REACT_APP_BASENAME=${{ env.REACT_APP_BASENAME }}
            NGINX_AUTH_USERNAME=${{ secrets.NGINX_AUTH_USERNAME }}
            NGINX_AUTH_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.NGINX_AUTH_PASSWORD }}

  deploy-backend:
    runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
    needs: [ build-backend ]

    steps:
      - id: string
        uses: ASzc/change-string-case-action@v1
        with:
          string: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_HOST }}/${{ github.repository }}:build-${{ github.run_number }}

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - run: docker rm -f ${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }} 2> /dev/null

      - run: >
          docker run
          --network=main
          --detach
          --restart unless-stopped
          --name=${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          ${{ steps.string.outputs.lowercase }}
```

I have github-runner and docker-registry in my server. Docker registry is running on the server, I checked it